# How to do any task every week in node-schedule?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-schedule

I'm using node-schedule package and I need some help. Can I do any task start of each week?

Answer (score 0):

The node-schedule packages uses the crontab syntax.
In order to run once a week you can do:

1 1 * * 1 “At 01:01 on Monday.”

https://crontab.guru/